# Command for enabling networking?

Tags: command-line, networking, wireless

What is the command for enabling networking and wireless using command line?

I have made a script that delays the startup apps for quicker boot times.

I have learned that disabling networking also helps in a quicker boot time.

I would like to add a command that shall enable networking and wireless in the shell script.

Comment: If the `networking start` answer makes stuff crash, it could be your delay script does something funky. Maybe you want to post the script, so we can see what you did ;)

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for `sudo service networking start` ?

I believe `network-manager` handles the networking and interface on Ubuntu 12.04 so it should be like:

```
sudo service network-manager start
```

**[EDIT]**
Just an update in support of my comment below, for automating `SUDO` when piping the password to it from external source use:

```
echo "password" | sudo -S service network-manager start
```

Which will not ask for the password interactively.

**`-S`** Switch here make `sudo` to read the password from standard input and not from terminal.

Comment: nope...error is-----> start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.94" (uid=1000 pid=6820 comm="start network-manager ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")

Comment: @Nirmik Sorry for this late reply, anyway.. Please have a look above I have updated the commands. You need to run it under elevated privileges.

Comment: also, if you want to automate the script for `sudo` whick will not proceed without the admin password you can store the password in script file like this `echo "p@$$w0rD" | sudo service network-manager start`

Comment: okay the sudo thing workd but the later part you said about 'echo "the password" | command' is not working as a command when i tried to test it in the commandline

Comment: Is there any specific error ? Can you post what exactly you run in terminal, just scribble your original password before posting ;)

Comment: bash: !": event not found..it looks like an error coz of "!" being a character in my passwd...how can i solve this?

Comment: i have to put the passwd in "" rite?

Comment: Just use single quotes for (!) exclamation sign alone. Like, if your password is **"s!de"** it will go like this `"s"'!'"de"`, So while echoing out the password wrap other characters in double quotes but ! sign in single quote. for the instance here is how you should do it: `echo "s"'!'"de" | sudo -S service network-manager start`. I added one more switch **-S** that is necessary here. I have updated above post about that.

Comment: Note: If you write password in the command, it will remain in the command history.

Answer (score 4):

When using [NetworkManager](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager) (its service running) there is no need for `sudo` to enable/disable *networking*.

Use [`nmcli`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/nmcli.1.html):

```
nmcli networking {on | off | connectivity}
```

`connectivity` get network connectivity state (full/none...).

Just for WiFi:

```
nmcli radio wifi {on | off}
```

Comment: Sometimes you need to start network-manager first, and then you can execute your command. To start networkmanager execute `sudo service network-manager start`

Answer (score 1):

to start network

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking start
```

to stop

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking stop
```

to restart

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

[Source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-restart-start-stop-networking-service-howto/)

Comment: nope! it crashed whole of unity! :(

Comment: Unity crash ? hmm strange issue . hope some one will help you